# Why XmlDocument declaration variable A change when B XmlDocument declared variable is modified?

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I receive a base  XML file, I need to create N XmlFiles with different content values. basically I do 
a copy, change some node values and create the new file without modifying the base one.

I add every XML document to a list of documents to do other processes and then to interact and create the N Files.
after my code executes I end up with all the files having the same info, even the base one is modified.
 I create a basic code to demonstrate it. thanks for any explanation about why is it happening.

```
    // file1.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<BOM>
    <BO>
        <AdmInfo>
            <Object>2</Object>
            <Version>2</Version>
        </AdmInfo>
        <BusinessPartners>
            <row>
                <CardCode>111111</CardCode>
                <CardName>MADERAS DE AGUADULCE, S.A</CardName>
                <GroupCode>P-Locales</GroupCode>
            </row>
        </BusinessPartners>

    </BO>
</BOM>
```

```
// C# code - method that change the value into the xmlFile.
     public XmlDocument ChangeValues(XmlDocument document, List<Tuple<string, string>> AtriValues )
        {

            XmlDocument NewXMLDocument = new XmlDocument();
            // pass the content to another XmlDocument 

            NewXMLDocument = document;

            foreach (var Atribute in AtriValues)
            {
                XmlElement root = NewXMLDocument.DocumentElement;
                XmlNodeList elemList = root.GetElementsByTagName(Atribute.Item1.ToString());
                IEnumerator ienum = elemList.GetEnumerator();
                while (ienum.MoveNext())
                {
                    XmlNode title = (XmlNode)ienum.Current;
                    // Console.WriteLine(title.InnerText);
                    title.InnerText = Atribute.Item2.ToString();

                    //xn[Atribute.Item1.ToString()].InnerText = Atribute.Item2.ToString();
                }
            }

            return NewXMLDocument;
        }
    // C# code- the main prg
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Util2 Util = new Util2();
            List<XmlDocument> Documents = new List<XmlDocument>();
            XmlDocument  xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();



            // load the XML file 
            xmlDocument.Load(@"C:\WIP\BaSe\TEST\file1.xml");

            // Save the base file 
            Documents.Add(xmlDocument);

            // Change the content of the document to create document A

            List<Tuple<string, string>> AtriValuesA = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

            AtriValuesA.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("CardCode", "9999"));
            AtriValuesA.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("GroupCode", "AA"));

            Documents.Add(Util.ChangeValues(xmlDocument, AtriValuesA));




            // Change the content of the document to create document B

            List<Tuple<string, string>> AtriValuesB = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

            AtriValuesB.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("CardCode", "2222"));
            AtriValuesB.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("GroupCode", "BB"));

            Documents.Add(Util.ChangeValues(xmlDocument, AtriValuesB));


            // get the document and then save then 

            Documents[0].Save(@"C:\WIP\BaSe\TEST\base.xml");
            Documents[1].Save(@"C:\WIP\BaSe\TEST\DOCA.xml");
            Documents[2].Save(@"C:\WIP\BaSe\TEST\DOCB.xml");

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `NewXMLDocument = document;` you are assigning a reference to the original XmlDocument object, so any changes apply to the original object.

Instead of assigning a reference, you need to clone the original object. I think you want something like this:

```
public XmlDocument ChangeValues(XmlDocument document, List<Tuple<string, string>> AtriValues )
{
  // Create the new document using the contents of the existing document.
  XmlDocument NewXMLDocument = (XmlDocument)document.CloneNode(true);

  foreach (var Atribute in AtriValues)
  {
    XmlElement root = NewXMLDocument.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList elemList = root.GetElementsByTagName(Atribute.Item1.ToString());
    IEnumerator ienum = elemList.GetEnumerator();
    while (ienum.MoveNext())
    {
      XmlNode title = (XmlNode)ienum.Current;
      // Console.WriteLine(title.InnerText);
      title.InnerText = Atribute.Item2.ToString();

      //xn[Atribute.Item1.ToString()].InnerText = Atribute.Item2.ToString();
    }
  }
  return NewXMLDocument;
}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.clonenode

Comment: Thanks, WileCau, your contribution points me to the right direction.  I used it on the function ChangeValues as you suggest and  I got the same wrong result. but using it before sending it to the function works perfectly. 
I thought I had to deal with passing the var by val  nor by ref. but I could not get how to do it. but this solution works too.

Comment: the line that sent to the function end up like this.     Documents.Add(Util.ChangeValues((XmlDocument)xmlDocument.CloneNode(true), AtriValuesA));

Answer (score 1):

All files are changing because you are changing the orginial xml document in ChangeValues function. The allocation below (new Document) has no effect, since you are assiging the reference to the original document to it.

```
XmlDocument NewXMLDocument = new XmlDocument();
// pass the content to another XmlDocument 

NewXMLDocument = document;
```

The quickest solution I would think of is to copy the original files first using `File.Copy` function to the new files names. 
After it, simply load the new files into the document and change it.

Following your example, the code would look something like:

```
var baseFile = @"C:\WIP\BaSe\TEST\base.xml";

var doc1 =  @"C:\WIP\BaSe\TEST\DOCA.xml";
var doc2 =  @"C:\WIP\BaSe\TEST\DOCB.xml";

File.Copy(baseFile, doc1);
File.Copy(baseFile, doc2);

// you might copy this to other function.

XmlDocument  xmlDocument1 = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument1.Load(doc1);

Util.ChangeValues(xmlDocument1, AtriValuesA);

xmlDocument1.Save(doc1);
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I save the file in order to demonstrate the issue  I'm facing, but the files are never saved to disk ( i allow to reed but not o write on disk on the server host "), there is a service that consumes the final documents object ( that contains all the XML documents store in the list). is there any way to clone it without affecting the original document?

Comment: Then it should be easier even. You can read the same file into a different objects - this is the easies clone.

Comment: I did that, add all the same file to de list<Document>  all the times i needed and then change the values with the function, but I got the same result since it changes the first one all other objects are affected.  i.e =  Documents.Add(Util.ChangeValues(Documents[1], AtriValuesA));